# Testing Fragments as Screens in single activity using Espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, android-espresso

I am using fragments as different screens in a single Activity in my app and navigating through fragment manager to different fragments.I am new to testing. I am using JUnit and espresso to test it.

I am able to test when i am testing first fragment. but I don't know how to navigate to next fragment and test that fragment. I am getting NoSuchViewExists exception.

Can anyone know the way or have a link to such article which gives information about this. There are links to navigate in activities but not in fragments.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you navigate between your fragments in your code?

Comment: I use fragment manager to navigate. I wrote a method in activity which i am using to change fragment.